# display more divs when clicking button jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have divs that are hidden, the first one is displayed, I want to click a button to display a div, each time I click the load more link, then disable the link once all the divs have been loaded.

Here is a jsfiddle to help illustrate what I am trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/8Re3t/1/

```
<p><a href="#" id="load-more">Load More</a></p>

<div class="group active" id="group1">
    Initially display
</div>

<div class="group" id="group2">
    1 Hide until you click load more
</div>

<div class="group" id="group3">
    2 Hide until you click load more
</div>

<div class="group" id="group4">
    3 Hide until you click load more
</div>

$("#load-more").click(function() {
  // show the next hidden div.group, then disable load more once all divs have been displayed
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about something like this:

```
var $group = $('.group');

$("#load-more").click(function() {
    // Prevent event if disabled
    if ($(this).hasClass('disable')) return;

    var $hidden = $group.filter(':hidden:first').addClass('active');
    if (!$hidden.next('.group').length) {
        $(this).addClass('disable');
    }
});
```

I add class `disable` to the link to visually make it look like disabled:

```
#load-more.disable {
    color: #AAA;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: default;
}
```

You can also unbind click event if you need it: `$(this).addClass('disable').off('click');`

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8Re3t/7/

Comment: To prevent handling the event anymore once all are displayed I would change the selector to: $("#load-more:not(.disable')") also I was working on a fiddle to handle this too, which you can see here http://jsfiddle.net/8Re3t/3/

Comment: @dfsq is there a way to automatically scroll to where the newly displayed div begins?

Comment: @dfsq thanks, I just realized my load more button is actually at the bottom of the page and not at the top. I apologize for not displaying the load more button at the bottom. It scrolls me but not like it should, thanks to me not providing that the button was at the bottom and you were coding for it to be at the top, could you revise that?

Comment: @dfsq nevermind, it works just fine. I really appreciate all the help.

Comment: @dfsq:- Hi its working fine.. but what if i want to load the div from left side.

Answer (score 1):

Posting my solution as a different answer in case you prefer it. There's more than one way to skin a cat (Note: I do not condone skinning cats)

```
$("#load-more").click(function(e) {
    // show the next hidden div.group, then disable load more once all divs have been displayed
    var t = $(this);
    if (t.data('disabled')){
        return;
    }

    var hiddenGroups = $('.group:not(:visible)');
    if (hiddenGroups.length > 0){
        hiddenGroups.first().show();
    } else{
        t.data('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8Re3t/3/

Comment: load more button is active even after loading all the divs.